# Meteor does not render css and keeps reloading the app when using external DDP Meteor instance

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, rendering, ddp

I tried to find out various ways why, and how this is happening but I can't seem to figure it out. I already asked this on #meteor on freenode but that channel is a little afk.

The problem is, my application stops rendering css and keeps reloading the page when I use a second meteor application as DDP source. (DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL).

Well, It renders the css for a split second, and then it resets again and the css is completely gone from the browser/dom.

I put my source code up on github, the app that is failing to render css is:
github.com/mdahiemstra/tripster/tree/master/src/app

and the meteor ddp server is:
github.com/mdahiemstra/tripster/tree/master/src/api

Pretty standard meteor setups, nothing too fancy. App is doing great when I do not include a DDP connection url.

I put a demo online too to see it failing in action:
App: http://oozio.nl:5000/ (using DDP of the meteor app "api")

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers!

--EDIT
With help of a kind irc user on #meteor we solved it for now by removing the autoupdate, but its hardly a fix and I think its a core meteor bug.

Comment: I posted Github issue about this issue [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3815), go in there to echo your issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL` instead use `DDP.connect()`:

```
DDPConnection = (Meteor.isClient) ? DDP.connect('http://myOtherServer.com') : {};

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    // set the new DDP connection to all internal packages, which require one
    Meteor.connection = DDPConnection;
    Accounts.connection = Meteor.connection;
    Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection('users');
    Meteor.connection.subscribe('users');
}

// When creating a collection use:
posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts", DDPConnection);
// And to subscribe use the DDP connection
DDPConnection.subscribe("mySubscription");
```